# Parse messagePack to Json with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, msgpack

I have that buffer

```
87 a1 41 a4 31 32 33 34 a1 42 a4 61 62 63 64 a1 43 a1 61 a1 44 a8 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 a1 45 a8 75 73 65 72 6e 61 6d 65 a1 46 a4 6e 61 6d 65 a1 47 a7 6e 61 6d 65 5f 6e 61
```

and I want to parse to this json

```
{
    "A": "1234",
    "B": "abcd",
    "C": "a",
    "D": "11111111",
    "E": "username",
    "F": "name",
    "G": "name_na"
}
```

Like [Cybershef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Hex(%27Auto%27)From_MessagePack()&input=ODcgYTEgNDEgYTQgMzEgMzIgMzMgMzQgYTEgNDIgYTQgNjEgNjIgNjMgNjQgYTEgNDMgYTEgNjEgYTEgNDQgYTggMzEgMzEgMzEgMzEgMzEgMzEgMzEgMzEgYTEgNDUgYTggNzUgNzMgNjUgNzIgNmUgNjEgNmQgNjUgYTEgNDYgYTQgNmUgNjEgNmQgNjUgYTEgNDcgYTcgNmUgNjEgNmQgNjUgNWYgNmUgNjE)

How can I do that with Python please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install msgpack:
`pip3 install msgpack`

And run the following code:

```py
>>> import msgpack
>>> hex_str = "87 a1 41 a4 31 32 33 34 a1 42 a4 61 62 63 64 a1 43 a1 61 a1 44 a8 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 a1 45 a8 75 73 65 72 6e 61 6d 65 a1 46 a4 6e 61 6d 65 a1 47 a7 6e 61 6d 65 5f 6e 61"
>>> bytes_array = bytes.fromhex(hex_str)
>>> msgpack.loads(bytes_array)
{'A': '1234', 'B': 'abcd', 'C': 'a', 'D': '11111111', 'E': 'username', 'F': 'name', 'G': 'name_na'}
```